# ServiceStack - Custom UserAuth/Details

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

Is it possible to configure a class that implements both IUserAuth and IUserAuthDetail and used it when registering the IAuthRepository?
Actually we use this class doing

`new OrmLiteAuthProvider<OurClass,OurClass>()`

ServiceStack throws the error “invalid column name ‘UserAuthId’” 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they're 2 different data model classes where `UserAuth` has a 1:M relationship with `UserAuthDetails`.

Just use the existing `UserAuthDetails` if you're trying to save classes.

Comment: the table UserAuthDetail is not necessary in our case, we’ve tried to merge this class into one for this reason, but if there is no possibility we will use the UserAuthDetail class